Typescript: pretents foo is not in type bar, while it is: how to debug
When I do tx.idbtrans, I have an error:
Error: Property 'idbtrans' does not exist on type 'Transaction & { fileInfo: EntityTable<FileInfo, "id">; }'. 
        await db.transaction("rw", x.myUndoTransactionsToApply.tables.flat(), async (tx) => {
          wmNormalUndoOrRedo.set(tx.idbtrans, 2); // 2 means we are in a redo operation
          if(x && x.myUndoTransactionsToApply) 

but if I check the transaction type (either in the documentation or in the source code since I'm using npm link), I can see that idbtrans DOES exist:
$ cat src/classes/transaction/transaction.ts
…
/** Transaction
 * 
 * https://dexie.org/docs/Transaction/Transaction
 * 
 **/
export class Transaction implements ITransaction {
…
  idbtrans: IDBTransaction;
…

Any idea how to debug this? For instance, can I print the full description of Transaction to see what property is supposed to be allowed in Transaction?

If you check it on Dexie github, idbtrans does not exists

The last version which idbtrans exists in Transaction was 7 years ago. I think they either forget to update the document, or have messed up the d.ts and not realized.

@RickyMo - Nice investigative work! FWIW, I think that's worth posting as an answer. With the docs still listing it, Tobias may not be the only person who runs into this, so it would be a useful question and answer for the site to have. @​tobiasBora - It's probably worth filing an issue on their github about the documentation being out of date.

If you check the source code on Dexie github, idbtrans does not exist in Transaction's type declaration.
The last version which idbtrans existed in Transaction was 7 years ago. I think they either forget to update the document, or have messed up the d.ts and not realized.
You can try manually editing your local node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.d.ts to add it back and see if this works for you. As you said it probably still exists in the class as suggested by transaction.ts.
export interface Transaction {
    db: Dexie;
    active: boolean;
    mode: IDBTransactionMode;
    idbtrans: IDBTransaction; //Add this line
    //tables: { [type: string]: Table<any, any> }; Deprecated since 2.0. Obsolete from v3.0.
    storeNames: Array<string>;
    explicit?: boolean;
    parent?: Transaction;
    on: TransactionEvents;
    abort(): void;
    table(tableName: string): Table<any, any>;
    table<T>(tableName: string): Table<T, any>;
    table<T, Key>(tableName: string): Table<T, Key>;
}

Or by adding these lines in your project's d.ts
declare module "dexie" {
    interface Transaction{
        idbtrans: IDBTransaction;
    }
}


Awesome, thanks a lot, just pushed a PR https://github.com/dexie/Dexie.js/pull/1985 Just, I'm not sure to sure to see, why don't I need to specify the whole interface Transaction in the declare module workaround?

That's call interface merging. In typescript you can declare multiple interface with the same name and they will all merge together. Here you are merging with the existing Transaction interface provided by dexie
